# URL Regex for a API call?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make it when you input a URL into a textbox it will take out the important parts of the URL that I would need to add into the HTTP request for the JSON response, but the issue is that I'm not sure of a regex code that could do this.

The JSON reqest URL looks like this

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/fourfiveseconds-brynny-quicky-bootleg-read-description.json?client_id=

and the URL to a track looks like this

https://soundcloud.com/dj-brynny/fourfiveseconds-brynny-quicky-bootleg-read-description

what then I'm hoping the regex would do is get the last string after the last / and return that so I can then add that into the JSON request.

Comment: What did you try and what wasn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that without regexp. Just use lastIndexOf:

```
var str = "https://soundcloud.com/dj-brynny/fourfiveseconds-brynny-quicky-bootleg-read-description";
str = str.substring( str.lastIndexOf("/")+1 );
```

Comment: It will produce `/soundcloud.com/dj-brynny/`

Comment: Thanks for that it answered another question I was running through my head :P. I'm currently using url.split('/').pop(-1) to get the text after the last '/' if anyone comes across this.

Comment: @Jordan Javascript's `.pop()` does not accept any parameter, so you can remove `-1`.

Comment: @Jordan If it helped you, you may gracefully accept the answer;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `url.split('/').pop()` and have your function set up like this:

```
function convertURL(url){
    return 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/'+ url.split('/').pop() +'.json?client_id=';
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('convert').addEventListener('click', displayNewURL, false);
displayNewURL();

function displayNewURL(){
    var originalURL = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = convertURL(originalURL);
}

function convertURL(url){
    return 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/'+ url.split('/').pop() +'.json?client_id=';
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p{
    margin: 0;
}

textarea{
    width: 90%;
    height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Input:</p>
<textarea id="input">https://soundcloud.com/dj-brynny/fourfiveseconds-brynny-quicky-bootleg-read-description</textarea>
<button id="convert">Convert</button>
<p>Result :</p>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with regular expression and captured groups:

```
var url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/fourfiveseconds-brynny-quicky-bootleg-read-description.json?client_id=";
var output = url.replace(/(http)(:\/\/)api\.(soundcloud\.com\/)tracks(\/[^\s]+)\.json\?[^\s]+/, ("$1s$2$3dj-brynny$4"));
```

Explanation:

we create capturing groups, `(http)` being the first one ($1), it matches the "http".

Than we match "://" with the second group ($2) being `:\/\/`. The backslashes are escaping the forward slashes.

After that comes "api." which we don't need. The dot is also escaped per backslash.

The third group ($3) is `soundcloud\.com\/`. Again escaping the dot and the backslash to match "soundcloud.com".

"tracks" don't have to be captured and we go to the fourth group ($4) `\/[^\s]+` which matches a forward slash and any non-space character once or more times. The sign "^" in the square brackets is negation and "\s" means any white space character. So it negates the white space characters. The "+" sing means the search pattern appears at least once (thus once or more).

In the end we have `\.json\?[^\s]+` which has to match ".json?" followed by at least on non-space character.

In the output we combine them adding the letter "s" after "http" and putting "dj-brynny" where "tracks" was. Eventually "dj-brynny" is a variable in which case you could create a function taking that variable as an argument.

I hope this helps.

EDIT:

Now I see my post doesn't answer your question. I had a wrong assumption and didn't read your last line.

Here is a correction that fits to your problem:

```
var url = "https://soundcloud.com/dj-brynny/fourfiveseconds-brynny-quicky-bootleg-read-description";
var output = url.replace(/https:\/\/soundcloud\.com\/[^\s]+\/([^\s]+)/, "$1");
```

The explanation of the regular expressions above should help with this example too.